# segmentation fault for the code

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

union type{
            int a;
            char b;
            int *p;
            char *s;
            int arr[10];
};

int fn(union type *exp){

    exp->p = exp->p+1;
    cout << *(exp->p);
    cout << "\n";
return 0;
}

int main(){

    union type *str;
    str->a = 10;
    str->b = 'n';
    str->p = &(str->a);
    cout << (str->p);
    cout << "\n";
    fn(str);
    cout << str->p;
    cout << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

This code is giving me segmentation fault. Is it because i need to allocate memory to the union explicitly using malloc?? I am new to coding and trying to learn c++.

Comment: Trying to learn C++ by using `malloc` and weird, pointless unions won't get you far. There's a list of good books in the FAQ that will.

Comment: Is there any reason str has to be a pointer to a type, instead of just a type? If you just remove the * and change every -> into a ., everything will work. (Well, in the fn prototype you might want to turn the * into a & instead of removing it.)

Comment: Also, even if you do malloc str (or replace it with a non-pointer), fn(str) is going to fail (but probably not segfault, unless you're lucky). You set str->p to a pointer to str itself, then increment it, so it's now pointing sizeof(int) bytes past str, which is either the middle of str, or whatever object comes after str in memory, or uninitialized memory, none of which are things you probably want to print as an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This code is giving me segmentation fault. Is it because i need to
>   allocate memory to the union explicitly using malloc??

Right. Your `str` pointer isn't pointing to valid memory location, it even not initialized. So, before writing `str->a` you need to set `str` to something.

Comment: i added this piece  to the code and it works: str = (union type *)malloc(sizeof(type));

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a pointer to a union, but the pointer is not pointing to any valid memory, which you need to either malloc/new.  What it is pointing to is undefined (garbage pointer).